# Question in relation to completing the square

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In description of "completing the square" at http://www.purplemath.com/modules/sqrquad.htm the following is given :

[image]

I'm having difficulty understanding the third part of the transformation.

Where is
$ -\frac{1}{4}$ derived from $-\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Why is $ -\frac {1}{4}$ squared to obtain $ \frac {1}{16}$ ?

Comment: Am I the only one who objects to a sentence like: "Move the other number over to the other side"? When a student proposed such an action in one of my classes, I'd go to the door and throw something to the other side of the corridor. After one or two of this, students would learn that you subtract (or add or multiply by) a number on both sides of the equal sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, to complete the square of something like $x^2 \pm Bx = \pm C$, you take half the coefficient of $x$, which is $B$, and then square it.

For the third step, they first take half of the $x$ coefficient, which is $-\frac{1}{2}$. Half of $-\frac{1}{2}$ is $-\frac{1}{4}$ since
$$ \frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{2} = \frac{-\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{2}{1}}= -\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2} = -\frac{1}{4}.$$

Then, they square $-\frac{1}{4}$ which is $\frac{1}{16}$ since
$$ \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2 = -\frac{1}{4} \cdot -\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{16}.$$

The reason why they add $\left (\frac{B}{2} \right)^2$ to both sides of the equation is to make a squared binomial:
$$x^2 + Bx + \left (\frac{B}{2} \right)^2 = \left(x + \frac{B}{2} \right)^2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's begin with the equation 
$$x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x = \frac{5}{4}$$
What the author wants to do is to create a perfect square on the left hand side.  That is, the author wants to transform the expression on the left hand side into the form $(a + b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$.  Assume that 
$$a^2 + 2ab = x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x$$
If we let $a = x$, then we obtain
\begin{align*}
x^2 + 2bx & = x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x\\
2bx & = -\frac{1}{2}x\\
\end{align*}
Since the equation $2bx = -\frac{1}{2}x$ is an algebraic identity that holds for each real number $x$, it holds when $x = 1$.  Thus,
\begin{align*}
2b & = -\frac{1}{2}\\
b & = -\frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}
Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
a^2 + 2ab + b^2 & = x^2 + 2\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)x + \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^2\\
                & = x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{16}
\end{align*}
If we add $1/16$ to the left hand side of the equation, we must add $1/16$ to 
the right hand side of the equation to balance it, which yields
$$x^2 - \frac{1}{2}x + \frac{1}{16} = \frac{5}{4} + \frac{1}{16}$$
By construction, the expression on the left hand side is the perfect square $(x - \frac{1}{4})^2$, so we obtain
$$\left(x - \frac{1}{4}\right)^2 = \frac{21}{16}$$
We can now solve the quadratic equation by taking square roots, which is why we wanted to transform the left hand side into a perfect square.

Answer (score 0):

If you have $(a+b)^2 = a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ and $a^2 = x^2, 2ab = -x/2$, then $a=x, b = -1/4$.
$1/16$ is $b^2$ which is needed to form $a^2 + 2ab + b^2$ in the LHS and move remain elements in the RHS.

Comment: You meant $1/16$ is $b^2$ rather than $-1/16$.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Oh, you're right, sure. Corrected.